# How to make a UML diagram with a class that has a main method and no fields

Tags: methods, uml, program-entry-point, class-diagram

I have a class that has a `main()` method and no fields and also it doesn't have a constructor.  This class is just a simple class in a larger project, that I did it all by myself and that is why I feel like something is wrong.

I have to document the project with an UML diagram. I don't know what am I supposed to write in the diagram for such a simple class. Just the static methods?

How do I write the main class in the UML?

Comment: You should learn about main method , a class that contains a main method is supposed to be executed as a program ,you cannot execute a class without a main method .. if for example you are in springBoot and this is the class of the application( that run the application) you dont need to add it to the uml diagram

Comment: Just don't. It's not a class but a technical issue coming from your programming langauge. Per convention a function called _main_ is used to trigger the whole program from the OS side (mostly based on a user command).

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is a situation that is common in class-only languages, [such as Java](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method) or [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line), where every code must be to encapsulated in a class.

In this case, the `main()` method is a *static* method that is called to start your application. Usually it is a technical requirement and not very important feature for the OO design.  This is why it rarely appears in a class diagram.

But it is a static method like any other, and in UML you could just want to show it as a static [operation](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html), by [underlining](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-core.html#static-feature) its name.