# Am I missing methods in this Java UML Diagram?

Tags: java, methods, uml

I'm a CS student and learning Java. For my assignment, I've created the below UML diagram for the code below. This diagram should contain class name, variables and methods.

However, I am not sure if I created a correct UML diagram. I think class name and variables are correct, they are all public data members, but I'm not sure if the method is correct. It seems only method in my code is main method.

Can you advise if I'm correct or not please?

Code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fName = "Students.txt";  // variable to store the file name
       
        // prompt to user to enter number of names 
        System.out.print("Enter the number of names: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();  // taking number of names
        // clear the input buffer
        sc.nextLine();
        
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>(number); // arraylist to store the entered names 

        // take number of input names from the user
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter name " + (i+1) + ": ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            names.add(name); // add name into arrayList
        }

        // sorting the names list
        Collections.sort(names);
        
        // store all names into the file Students.txt
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fName); // open a file for writing names 
            
            for(String name:names){  // write names into files Student.txt
                fw.write(name + "\n");
            }
            
            fw.close(); // close file 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //prompt to user to enter a name which you want to elininate from the file
        System.out.print("\nEnter a name that you want to eliminated from the file: ");
        String removeName = sc.nextLine();

        // make a temporary file to copy all the names except the names which you want to remove
        String tempFName = "StudentsTemp.txt";

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fName)); // open Student.txt file for reading names

            // open temp file to write all the data except eliminated name
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFName);

            // read all data
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String name = scan.nextLine(); // read name
                //check the readed name with the user entered eliminated name
                if(name.compareTo(removeName)!=0){
                    fw.write(name + "\n");
                }
            }
            // close file
            fw.close();
            //delete the old file
            File old = new File(fName);
            old.delete();

            
            File newFile = new File(tempFName); //rename the temporary file to the old file name
            newFile.renameTo(old);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

UML Diagram:
[image: uml diagram]

I think only method is main method, but what about rename, delete, compareto, etc.? aren't these methods should be included to uml diagram as well?

Comment: I don't think this is correct because the variables are declared inside the local scope of the main method and are not class fields. If the variables were extracted to be fields of the FileTest class then it would be correct. Imagine if you had several different methods. The variable list would quickly become unmanageable. 

Your main method declaration looks correct though.

You should only have methods that your are creating in the UML diagram for your class. The rename, delete, compareTo are methods of another class and are not applicable.

Comment: UML is for objected-oriented programming. But you did not write any classes. You wrote imperative code. **So you have nothing to document in UML.** And, no, local variables and method calls do not belong in a UML diagram.

Comment: According to the class diagram, you need to create 5 public _global_ variables an one public method (main).  Also, your `main` method is not static since it is not underlined.

Comment: @hfontanez thank you so much, your diagram and explanation is really helpful. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @rsav in that case, don't forget to upvote. And, if the answer helped you solve your problem, I will appreciate it if you select it as the best answer.

Comment: @JakeHenry thank you so much for your help, i get the idea thanks to your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question per title: no. But it's utterly wrong. There is no class in the sense of a class. This is what Java came up with to place that operation `main`. And that's the only operation in this pseudo-class. Nothing else. No attributes. No other operation.

Whether you show the full parameter details (the type is shown with brackets to make it appear as array though UML does not care much here at all)

[image]

or just the skeleton

[image]

is on you. Anyhow, I would not create any class for this since it's only a Java makeshift.

Answer (score 2):

From a Java point of view, the *class* `FileTest` is very simple:  it has no *[field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)*  and has only one [`static` *method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2) `main()`.

This can be modelled in UML with a very simple class, which has no *properties* (field) and one static *operation*:

[image: just one class box, with an underline operation]

Static members are underlined. Public members should be preceded with a `+`. The UML syntax regarding the parameters is slightly different from Java, and the absence of return type (`void` in Java) should be represented in UML with no type at all for the operation.

From an OO design perspective, this class is not super-interesting, as it is only a wrapper around a mandatory static function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320077/3723423)). By the way, local method variables in Java are implementation details of an operation and not class properties.

Comment: thank you so much, this was the conclusion i reached at the end as well. thank you for your detailed explanation, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a UML class diagram "cheat sheet"

### The box

- Class diagram has three boxes, whereas interfaces only have two
- The top section of the diagram is reserved for the class or interface name
- The bottom section of the diagram is reserved for the class or interface methods
- The middle section of a class diagram is reserved for its (***global***) variables

### Visibility (access) modifiers

- `+` public access (it is acceptable to omit this symbol)
- `-` private access
- `#` protected access
- `~` default access. I think this was not originally part of class diagrams, but was added later to accommodate Java's package-private modifier

### Other notes

- Static members (class or variables) are denoted by underlining the name
- Constant fields are denoted by CAPITALIZING the name
- A method's parameter list is defined to the right of the method name inside parentheses. It shall include type and variable name separated by colon. For example: `+ myMethod(name : String, value : int)`
- A method return type is defined to the right of the method name separated by a colon. For example: `+ myMethod(String, int) : void`
- Constructors (obviously) won't have return types

### A (simple) example

This is a simpe example of a class diagram putting in practice all elements in this cheat sheet.

[image: A simple example of a class diagram]

Comment: @qwerty_so That is PRECISELY what I had in mind. LOL Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Nice cheat sheet. A graphic example showing the underline could be nice (plantuml can generate this quickly from text). By the way, double is not a build in UML type and would require a Java profile to be defined.

Comment: Using only primitive UML types,  inserting a case for abstract operations,  sticking to the UML rules for constructors,  it would be something like:  https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/TP3FIWCn4CRlUOe1BrrKy5mGMjTBmLQmnViqEzPWDbcIIQ6MFf6FuArFvj3T9bhmaZ_vVfdvvfj4ni2fjIf-6DTXm1OYxop96eo-KBJ56ASioZenpRHtI_D9SATE0intzMdVgslOHqOs-h1SJLUp6khdXPmMAnZ3Khwx3GZJfRKrUkPONcMb3GLr1LtmJ9gfUV9kKuHRQEWDa-K7xosXap_dqprmI2H45ymMcHwz5AOnl13QyjhtpGQa__6h3YJAyJjR7rK239T_28SjvIf_yNwWLs-QEV6xRoxW6zYYJOEnAlCzEwh6mpmYx74TEQ3cGuzCX-kvR5LoAL7tMqPosnB1RsUcX5w1EgW9kIQrzWS0

Comment: @hfontanez I guess someone downvoted (not me) because it was too general and not addressing the specific issues in the question.  Don’t worry about that. Maybe add an introductory sentence about the public static method.