# UML Diagram for methods in main class

Tags: java, methods, uml, mainclass

I'm working on my project and wondering whether if I should represent all the methods in the main class as **static** by drawing a line under the name of the methods including the main method.

For example:

```
-------------------
    MainClass
-------------------

-------------------

+Main()
______

+Othermethod()
______________

-------------------
```

Should I keep the line under the othermethod() or I should remove it and keep it only under the main method?

Comment: I don’t understand? If the method **is** static, then in UML use underlining. 

PS: if you want to use text files for UML you should consider using PlantUML.

Comment: So I should underline all the methods in the main class @ChristophDahlen

Comment: No, just the static ones (like `main`, lower-cased btw.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. What is than `Main()` and what is `Othermethod()`. The way it is one can only guess. (Besides, an operation named _Main_ seems rather pointless just like _Othermethod_)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I missing methods in this Java UML Diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321021/am-i-missing-methods-in-this-java-uml-diagram)

Comment: Othermethod() is a static method also.

Comment: Okay thanks for your time I got my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static operations of a class, whether main() or other should be underlined. Non static operations should not be underlined:

[image]

If you'd make shortcuts on this notation, only showing some of the static methods as static, your model would be confusing, and could lead to errors in the implementation.

If you're using ASCII art, the underlining is very cumbersome and confusing.  In this case, you should prefer the `{static}` adornment, in textual form:

```
,---------------------------------.
|MainClass                        |
|---------------------------------|
|...                              |
|+{static} main()                 |
|+otherNonStaticOperation()       |
|+{static} otherStaticOperation() |
`---------------------------------'
```

*By the way, [plantuml](https://plantuml.com) can generate both, graphic and ascii art, for the same [model](https:////www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/POuz3W9124PxJa6fCPbuX3LM5chX2SQHHEByR80jTBDt5wSosdmGtYCmg4MngMJG1zSnIYoezipaAPn-ICfHTMTEhfFH8RLwuHVX5g0JF4Qk-zxDW1X2yDpCVi8uBLYShjQVKRCxoSctEpcF95wRms-_Ity68YmmKBtvPsy0):*

```
@startuml
skinparam style strictuml
skinparam classAttributeIconSize 0

class MainClass {
  ...
  +{static} main()
  +otherNonStaticOperation()
  +{static} otherStaticOperation()  
}
@enduml
```