# How do I create a class diagram based on this method?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Recently the concept of class diagrams was introduced to me and my assignment requires that I create a class diagram. I think I understand the first two sections of a class diagram but am unsure of how to denote this method.

[image: my code for a simple program]

I have made an attempt here:

[image: attempt]

Comment: Never use pictures of code! It isnt really that hard to just copy the code here onto StackOverflow! By doing this you can help us run the code without having to type out every line from an image ;>

Comment: Your diagram is incorrect since your class has no instance variables, only a static main method. You also don't put logic/math in class diagrams

Comment: I would store width and length together as `floorDimensions: Dimensions` where that class has  `length`, `width`, and `height` variables.

Comment: From the code, you only have one method in the class, so that is all the diagram should show. You don't show local varaibles in a class diagram, nor do you show any calculations.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I suspect that the diagram is partially correct, but that OP didn't understand that some features he put inside main() belong in reality to the class and not to main's implementation, as Mr Polywhirl suggests ;-)

Comment: I'm revisiting your question from a while back. And now I notice that your Java code has many compiler errors, so writing a valid UML diagram for the code isn't helpful. From the comments, it appears that you should have several methods other than `main()` as I show in my answer below. Those methods should be included in the UML diagram. But you also need to learn the syntax for methods in Java, if you haven't by now.

Answer (score 3):

The class diagram should just include the members of the class, not any local variables or calculations:

```
-------------------
| RentalApartment |
-------------------
| main()          |
-------------------
```

That's it. I don't remember how to indicate that the method is static, so I leave that for you to add. Also, you might need to add the return type of the method.

Comment: The static features should be underlined.  Unfortunately,  the current UML specifications no longer mentions an alternate textual notation,  but the former `{static}` adornment of previous UML versions is still widely understood. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74436804/3723423).

Answer (score 2):

First you will need a class. I would only store two instance variables for the `RentalAppartment` class. This only includes the `dimensions` and the `cost`.

Everything else can be calculate me from these variables.

```java
package org.example;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class AppartmentDriver {
    private static final NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double cost = 1000.00f;
        Dimensions dimensions = new Dimensions(10, 20);
        RentalAppartment rentalAppartment = new RentalAppartment(dimensions, cost);

        System.out.printf("Area: %.2f sq feet%n", rentalAppartment.getArea());
        System.out.println("VAT: " + currencyFormatter.format(rentalAppartment.getVat()));
        System.out.println("Total Cost: " + currencyFormatter.format(rentalAppartment.getTotalCost()));
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

public class RentalAppartment {
    private Dimensions dimensions; // Asuming feet
    private double cost;

    public RentalAppartment() {
        this.dimensions = new Dimensions();
    }

    public RentalAppartment(Dimensions dimensions, double cost) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return dimensions.getLength() * dimensions.getWidth();
    }

    public double getVat() {
        return this.cost * 0.2f;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() {
        return this.cost + this.getVat();
    }

    public Dimensions getDimensions() {
        return dimensions;
    }

    public void setDimensions(Dimensions dimensions) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(double cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

class Dimensions {
    private double length, width;

    public Dimensions() {
        this.length = 0;
        this.width = 0;
    }

    public Dimensions(double length, double width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

Output of `AppartmentDriver`:

```
Area: 200.00 sq feet
VAT: $200.00
Total Cost: $1,200.00
```

Here is the associated UML for the classes described above:

```
   +-----------------------------------+
   |         AppartmentDriver          |
   +-----------------------------------+
   | - currencyFormatter: NumberFormat |
   +-----------------------------------+
   | + main(String[]): void            |
   +-----------------------------------+
                   |
                   v
+----------------------------------------+
|           RentalAppartment             |
+----------------------------------------+
| - dimensions: Dimensions               |
| - cost: double                         |
+----------------------------------------+
| + RentalAppartment()                   |
| + RentalAppartment(Dimensions, double) |
| + getArea(): double                    |
| + getVat(): double                     |
| + getTotalCost(): double               |
| + getDimensions(): Dimensions          |
| + setDimensions(Dimensions)            |
| + getCost(): double                    |
| + setCost(double)                      |
+----------------------------------------+
                   |
                   v
     +------------------------------+
     |          Dimensions          |
     +------------------------------+
     | - length: double             |
     | - width: double              |
     +------------------------------+
     | + Dimensions()               |
     | + Dimensions(double, double) |
     | + getLength(): double        |
     | + setLength(double)          |
     | + getWidth(): double         |
     | + setWidth(double)           |
     +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Congratulations. Your analysis of the problem deals at the same time with OP's erroneous diagram, but also with OP's misunderstanding about the class nature which lead to wrong code.  I think nobody upvoted this answer, despite it is up to the point, because of the length of the code.  Maybe you could start with a first paragraph making a summary of the different points that need to be addressed before digging in the details ?

Answer (score 1):

> *"... am unsure of how to denote this method. ..."*

A *UML* diagram typically outlines the *[members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)* of a class; the *fields* and *methods*.

In this case, you would just denote the *main* method, optionally with parameters.

Additionally, you could provide notes for the class below the *members*.

```
+-----------------------------+
|       RentalApartment       |
+-----------------------------+
| +main(String[]): void       |
+-----------------------------+
| Class used to print         |
|  - floor length and width   |
|  - area                     |
|  - cost                     |
|  - VAT                      |
|  - and total cost           |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: The static features should be underlined or use the obsolete but sill widely understood  {static} adornment. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74436804/3723423). the additional compartment that you mention is in fact not for notes in general (these should be provided in note boxes outside the class and attached with a dotted line) but for responsibilities of the class (your example could qualify for the latter).